# How can I force browsers to check for a new version despite a caching directive max-age 30 days?

Tags: iis, cache

I had the following declaration in my website's root:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

I think this tells browsers not to look for new versions of any file unless it's older than 30 days - is that correct?

This was not my intention and I've since modified the instruction, but while some browsers are now updating despite the old instruction, some are not.  Is there a way to force browsers to look for a new version with immediate effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the browser doesn't make a request for the file (till it expires) then you don't get to give it a new caching directive.

However, I note that the staticContent bit.  IF this is only applied to static content, and not your html pages which are (likely to be) dynamic, then you can change the urls referred to in the html.  That may or not be an easy thing to organise, depending on how you generate your content, but it's a very sound strategy in general.

Eg you might take your css file path (or similarly any other static content you refer to), plus a timestamp for when it was last changed, concatenate those strings, and make an md5 hash of them.  then use an URL like http://example.com/static/{your_md5sum}.css in your html, and make a copy or symlink off the css content ready to be served at that path.  You can then always serve your css links with multi-year expiry times, but stop using old versions whenever you want.  It's also good if you want to keep old versions available, because for instance they work with old versions of pages which people may have copied elsewhere on the web, or old emails, or whatever (the latter more for images than css).

A slightly simpler mechanism might be to just add a timestamp to your paths like http://example.com/foo/bar.css?t=1377075018, with the timestamp taken from the modification time of the file on your local server.